# How to retrieve contents from stderr in C?

Tags: c

I have an `stderr` statement having a sentence in it.

I want to get that content and push it to the standard output using `printf()`.

`fprintf(stderr, "Hello world!");`

Now, I want to get this **Hello World!** and print it using `printf()` to the standard output.

**Is it feasible ?**

Comment: You mean capture data that the process has already written to stderr? In the same process, or in a calling process? In general I expect you can't - it may already have been flushed from any buffers in your process to the pipe, file or console. Or did you mean intercept the output at the point it was written?

Comment: It is in the same processes. Yes, I mean capture data that the process has already written to stderr. In other words, the printf() call follows immediately after the `fprintf()` call.

Comment: Maybe you could redirect `stderr` to temporary file with `freopen` before data has been written. Then you could read the file and print to `stdout` afterwards.

Comment: So you are saying that it is not possible what I am trying to achieve ?

Comment: If you are trying to `fread` directly from `stderr`, I doubt it will work. It probably depends on your implementation, but `stderr` is *output* stream, which is usually not read.

Comment: But `stderr` is a separate standard error stream and `stdout` is another standard output stream. So isn't it possible to read from one stream and push it in another stream ?

Comment: Why don't you just write to both?

Comment: @Elyasin I can. But it is just a thought came to my mind. I am curious if it is possible at all. If not then why ? But logically it seams feasible since these are two separate streams.

Answer (score 1):

By default the stderr does not have any buffer. So, we need to set the buffer for the stderr.

you have to change the buffer for the stderr before any operation done on stderr.

To setting the buffer for the stderr, you can use [setbuf()](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/setbuf.3.html) to set the buffer for the stderr.

Example :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    setbuf(stderr, buf);
    fprintf(stderr, "Hello, world!\n");
    printf("%s", buf);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:-

```
Hello, world! 
Hello, world!
```

In this example, the variable buf contains what ever you written in stderr, it stored in the buf character array. Using that character array you can print that in stdout.